# import ActionBarSherlock to eclipse

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I want to use ActionBarSherlock and HoloEveryWhere in my Android app

but when I import ActionBarSherlock Library in Eclipse, imported library contains many errors !!!

Library folder screenshot : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs7lO.png) (Updated)

Problems screenshot : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faQkp.png)

How can I fix it ?

---

**My problem solved :)**

**I Changed Java compiler level to 1.6 .**

Comment: check the Problems: Window -> Show View -> Problems

Comment: You can make your update an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ActionBarSherlock` library must be built against the last version(or `4.0`) of Android(and the projects that use the library also have to be built against `4.0` or `4.1`). 
*Right click the `ActionBarSherlock` library project -> Properties -> Android -> Check Android 4.1 -> Ok*

More about this can be found on the library's site - > http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Updated:
Another possible reason for the errors is an incorrect compliance level.
*Right click project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Set the compliance level to `1.6`*

See if this solves the problems.

Comment: I Check Android 4.1 and some problems solved . but it contain errors yet. I updated screenshots in first post .

Comment: @M.jack See my updated answer. If this doesn't solve the errors see what exactly does the error tells you and update the question again.